# process.env.NODE_ENV is translated in main.js to development

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, nestjs

I am using NX 15.8 with NestJs 9.

I have a file named boot.ts with the following function:

```
export function boot(): void {
  const timezone = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone;
  process.env.TZ = timezone;

  const NODE_ENV: string = process.env.NODE_ENV;
  ...
```

The last line contains a process.env.NODE_ENV.

If I look at the main.js after building the project, I see:

```
function boot() {
  const timezone = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone;
  process.env.TZ = timezone;
  const NODE_ENV = "development";
..
```

I am not sure if webpack is translating it.

But I want to keep it, how it was in the ts file. I want to set the environment myself during startup